# Altium Designer update nets in SchDoc from PcbDoc

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I have an Altium Designer project with a PcbDoc and a SchDoc file. For some reason a few nets (connections) in PcbDoc are not present in SchDoc. Can I update SchDoc from PcbDoc so that schematic connections (wires) would be added automatically?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, from the PcbDoc file, just click on Update Schematics from the Design menu.

It will suggest you the changes to apply, and you just click on execute changes.

Beware that it will just add the missing connections with net labels rather than pretty wires.

Comment: Just the missing connections without pretty wires would be fine. But still I can't figure out how to do that. I clicked Tools -> Annotate Schematics -> Back Annotate and Altium Designer prompted for an ECO file.

Comment: Just ignore the prompt and continue, it should come up with a window where it suggests the changes and gives you the option to backannotate

Comment: Still no luck. The 'Annotate' window appears but the 'Accept Changes (Create ECO)' button is disabled.

Comment: I have corrected the solution. It has been a long time since I needed to do that.

Comment: I've tried that. I guess it is not possible in Altium Designer. Maybe it could have been done in earlier versions.

Comment: I have tried to force the  change in one of my old designs by removing a net in the schematic and pushing the data back to it  from the PCB; it does spot the differences, and prompts you if you want to continue, but then comes up with an interface that list the differences, including the missing net. no matter what I tell it, this net won't appear in the ECO. I am starting to doubt this is possible to do, and that my memory is tricking me. I will look at it again with a fresh mind tomorrow, and change my answer accordingly.